# Multiple PhoneStateListeners being called

Tags: android, service, phone-state-listener

I have an app where I have a PhoneStateListener listening for calls.  I am using an IntentService to upload call information to a database.  I make a new PhoneStateListener in the onCreate() in my MainActivity.java

```
callStateListener = new CallStateListener(this.getApplicationContext(), false);
telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

I ideally want the PhoneStateListener to run all the time regardless if onDestroy() is called, the app is closed, or even the process is killed.

It stays on after you minimize the app.  And it also stays on after you hit the back button and onDestroy() is called.  But since onDestroy() is called onCreate() is called the next time I open the app and a new PhoneStateListener is made.  Now if a call is made two of the same calls are uploaded.  If I were to hit the back button again and reopen the app then 3 PhoneStateListeners would be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's calling it multiple times as you're not unregistering the listener. To do so, in your onDestroy() method add:

```
telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

For your "ideal case", you should use a background Service instead of an Activity to do the listening.

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem.  I used a BroadcastReceiver to call the PhoneStateListener.

Comment: Glad I helped! Feel free to vote up for the answer if it helped you :)